# Hide Input Focus in Chrome / Safari

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web application that uses input fields. When a user puts the cursor in one of those fields, the field has a yellow or blue outline. IE works as intended. Is there a way to hide this focus style?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you intended to let users not using a mouse know where the focus is? Bearing in mind that they might not be able to see the caret.

Comment: This should NOT be removes, the focus online, for accessibility reasons. Please take a look at: http://outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#inputFieldId:focus, #inputFieldId:active {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this css style:

```
outline: 0
```

Comment: That totally depends on what elements he wants to match on. The CSS rule is what the question is begging, not the selector for it.